# Setting time and date to date picker and time picker in android

Tags: android, timepicker, android-datepicker

I am using a date picker and time picker in my application. I want to set the date and time when the page loads. Is this possible? How so?

Answer (score 117):

I solved a similar problem of mine as follows

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

datePicker.updateDate(year, month, day);

timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(min);
```

Comment: setHour() and setMinute() since Android API 23.

Comment: The update month is from 0 (Jan) to 11 (Dec), but days begin at 1.

Answer (score 14):

### Using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

*[JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is an extremely popular and useful library for handling dates and times in Java. If you're not using it, I highly recommend taking a look at it.*

Here's a simple example of how I set a `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` from a `DateTime` object, which could be the current date or any date from the past or future (the attribute in this case is called `inspected_at`):

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.inspected_at_date);
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.inspected_at_time);

DateTime inspected_at = DateTime.now()                // Typically pulled from DB.

int year    = inspected_at.getYear() ;
int month   = inspected_at.getMonthOfYear() - 1;      // Need to subtract 1 here.
int day     = inspected_at.getDayOfMonth();  
int hour    = inspected_at.getHourOfDay();
int minutes = inspected_at.getMinuteOfHour();

datePicker.updateDate(year, month, day);              // Set date.

timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);                      // Set time.
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minutes);
```

Hope that helps.

JP

Comment: If you're reading this question and you don't know what JodaTime is, take some time to check it out. It has a lot of advantages over java.util.Calendar

Comment: It should be noted that Java8 introduced the java.time package, which provides excellent support for handling dates and times without requiring a third-party dependency on JodaTime.

Answer (score 7):

There is a `updateDate` method for the DatePicker.

Here is what I use in one of my app, not using a dialog:

```
//set datePicker to position
String date_saved = project_row.getString(
    project_row.getColumnIndex("project_startdate"));

int day  = Integer.parseInt(date_saved.substring(0,2));
int year = Integer.parseInt(date_saved.substring(5,9));
String month = date_saved.substring(2,5);
int month_code = getMonthInt(month);

project_startdate_data = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.project_startdate_data);
project_startdate_data.updateDate(year, month_code, day);
```

where `project_row` is my cursor, and the date is saved in the column `project_startdate` like `22MAY2012`

and you need this:

```
private int getMonthInt(String month) {
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("JAN")) return 0;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("FEB")) return 1;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("MAR")) return 2;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("APR")) return 3;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("MAY")) return 4;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("JUN")) return 5;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("JUL")) return 6;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("AUG")) return 7;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("SEP")) return 8;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("OCT")) return 9;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("NOV")) return 10;
    if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("DEC")) return 11;

    //return -1 if month code not found
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this [How to use date picker dialog](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html). and use update function in onCreate(); if by page loads you mean activity starts.... hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html).

Use `showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);` function in `onCreate();`

Comment: i am not displaying date time picker as dialouges

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in kotlin

```
private fun setTime(hours: Int, minutes: Int) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            binding.timePickerLayout.timePicker.hour = hours
            binding.timePickerLayout.timePicker.minute = minutes
        } else {
            binding.timePickerLayout.timePicker.currentHour = hours
            binding.timePickerLayout.timePicker.currentMinute = minutes
        }
    }
```